# Copying files from HDFS to S3 on EMR cluster using S3DistCp

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hdfs, amazon-emr, s3distcp

I am copying **800 avro files**, size around **136 MB**, from **HDFS** to **S3** on **EMR cluster**, but Im getting this exception:

```
8/06/26 10:53:14 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 91%
18/06/26 10:53:14 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1529995855123_0003_r_000006_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Reducer task failed to copy 1 files: hdfs://url-to-aws-emr/user/hadoop/output/part-00258-3a28110a-9270-4639-b389-3e1f7f386ed6-c000.avro etc
        at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.CopyFilesReducer.cleanup(CopyFilesReducer.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:635)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:390)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

The configuration for the EMR cluster is:

```
core-site           fs.trash.checkpoint.interval     60
core-site           fs.trash.interval                60
hadoop-env.export   HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS               -Xmx10g
hdfs-site           dfs.replication                  3
```

Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit:**

Running the **hdfs dfsadmin -report** command, gives the following result:

```
[hadoop@~]$ hdfs dfsadmin -report
Configured Capacity: 79056308744192 (71.90 TB)
Present Capacity: 78112126204492 (71.04 TB)
DFS Remaining: 74356972374604 (67.63 TB)
DFS Used: 3755153829888 (3.42 TB)
DFS Used%: 4.81%
Under replicated blocks: 126
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 63
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0
```

It suggests that the block are missing. Does it mean that I have to re-run the program again? And if I see the output of Under replicated blocks, it says 126. It means 126 blocks will be replicated. How can I know, will it replicate the missing blocks?

Also, the value of **Under replicated blocks** is 126 for the last 30 minutes. Is there any way to force to it to replicate quickly?

Comment: Co incidentally, I am facing the same issue now but i do not have any missing blocks

Answer (score 1):

I got the same "Reducer task failed to copy 1 files" error and I found logs in HDFS /var/log/hadoop-yarn/apps/hadoop/logs related to the MR job that s3-dist-cp kicks off.

```
hadoop fs -ls /var/log/hadoop-yarn/apps/hadoop/logs
```

I copied them out to local:

```
hadoop fs -get /var/log/hadoop-yarn/apps/hadoop/logs/application_nnnnnnnnnnnnn_nnnn/ip-nnn-nn-nn-nnn.ec2.internal_nnnn
```

And then examined them in a text editor to find more diagnostic information about the detailed results of the Reducer phase. In my case I was getting an error back from the S3 service. You might find a different error.